# MySQL / SQL : delete lowest value rows

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

Having issues only updating a table where values have increased.

### My scenario :

Imagine you have a database of structure like so, which represents all a programmes peak audience values split by channel and device.

Every 5 mins you are pushing new data into this table,

Where the goal is to only update values where the programme's peak views has increased

eg increased "event_peak_views" from a unique "platform_id AND channel_epg_id AND event_start"

My current approach is to quick insert new values every 5 mins, then select the lowest peak values for any given programme and delete them.

There MUST be a better way, given the data sets are rather large at several million rows, anyone got any better suggestions than my own shoddy approach ?

### Current Table Layout

```
`entry_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`platform_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`channel_epg_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`event_start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`event_peak_views` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
INDEX `platform_id` (`platform_id`),
INDEX `channel_epg_id` (`channel_epg_id`),
INDEX `event_start` (`event_start`)
```

### My Delete/Select lowest values SQL

```
DELETE victim
FROM
    Livescrape_data_live_historical_events as victim,
    Livescrape_data_live_historical_events as comparsion
WHERE
    victim.entry_id<>comparsion.entry_id
    AND victim.event_start=comparsion.event_start
    AND victim.platform_id=comparsion.platform_id
    AND victim.channel_epg_id=comparsion.channel_epg_id
    AND (
        (victim.event_peak_views < comparsion.event_peak_views)
        OR (
            victim.event_peak_views = comparsion.event_peak_views
            AND victim.entry_id > comparsion.entry_id
        )
);
```

Comment: is your current delete query not working? do you get any errors ? I am not entirely sure that is correct though but it looks like a valid starting point.

Comment: seems to work fine for me for the moment, it's more a efficiency question, for when the data grows to a few million rows, at the moment it seems fine, but full table scan i think will bite me in the ass eventually.

rather than asking how to i do something, I'm asking how do i do something better